# AMP Validator Errors

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux, next.js, amp-html

I am new to next/amp, I am using amp with nextjs and in dev mode amp validator is throwing errors which I am unable to wrap my head around. Following are the errors that are being thrown:

1. CSS syntax error in tag 'style amp-custom' - saw invalid at rule '@import'
2. CSS syntax error in tag 'style amp-custom' - saw invalid at rule '@charset'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain your problem more elaborately and show what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. AMP has certain CSS code requirements. Your CSS code probably contains something like this:

```
<style amp-custom>
  @charset "UTF-8";
  @import 'custom.css';
</style>
```

Just remove this code from: `<style amp-custom></style>`

Read the official documentation: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages/?format=websites